# What is the best way to return more than 2 different variable type values in Scala

Tags: scala

It's been while Since I've started working on scala and I am wondering what kind of variable type is the best when I create a method which requires to return multiple data.

let's say If I have to make a method to get user info and it'll be called from many places.

```
  def getUserParam(userId: String):Map[String,Any] = {
    //do something
    Map(
      "isExist" -> true,
      "userDataA" -> "String",
      "userDataB" -> 1 // int
    )
  }
```

in this case, the result type is `Map[String,Any]` and since each param would be recognized as `Any`, You cannot pass the value to some other method requiring something spesifically.

```
def doSomething(foo: String){}
val foo = getUserParam("bar")
doSomething(foo("userDataA")) // type mismatch error
```

If I use `Tuple`, I can avoid that error, but I don't think it is easy to guess what each indexed number contains.

and of course there is a choice to use `Case Class` but once I use case class as a return type, I need to import the case class where ever I call the method.

What I want to ask is what is the best way to make a method returning more than 2 different variable type values.

Comment: go with the case class

Comment: What would you expect to happen with `doSomething(foo("userDataA"))` if `userDataA` did not exist? If it does always exist, I agree with @SethTisue and say, go with the case class

Comment: `userDataA` always exists. it could be `None` though

Comment: If `usersDataA` always exists and can be `None`, it must conversely be `Some("some value")` in the defined state, i.e. it would still be a type mismatch for `doSomething`. A case class of `Option` values is still the best, but `doSomething` needs to be able to deal with an `Option[String]` as well

Comment: @ArneClaassen I know the basics.what I wanted to tell you is that it never be undefined.even If it has no value on it.or need I edit question to let you get satisfied??
I assume you understand that the whole code in the question is just a example that's why you asked  if `userDataA` does always exist or not eventhough it's explicitly defined as "String". and then you are saying "then the question code is wrong" wtf

Comment: @suish I was not trying to attack your question, just asking what I felt were questions to clarify your intent of what `foo` should produce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three options. Even though you might like the third option (using anonymous class) it's actually my least favorite. As you can see, it requires you to enable reflective calls (otherwise it throws a compilation warning). Scala will use reflection to achieve this which is not that great.

Personally, if there are only 2 values I use tuple. If there are more than two I will use a case class since it greatly improves code readability. The anonymous class option I knew it existed for a while, but I never used that it my code.

```
import java.util.Date

def returnTwoUsingTuple: (Date, String) = {
    val date = new Date()
    val str = "Hello world"
    (date,str)
}

val tupleVer = returnTwoUsingTuple
println(tupleVer._1)
println(tupleVer._2)


case class Reply(date: Date, str: String)
def returnTwoUsingCaseClass: Reply = {
    val date = new Date()
    val str = "Hello world"
    Reply(date,str)
}

val caseClassVer = returnTwoUsingCaseClass
println(caseClassVer.date)
println(caseClassVer.str)


import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
def returnTwoUsingAnonymousClass = {
    val date = new Date()
    val str = "Hello world"
    new {
        val getDate = date
        val getStr = str
    }
}

val anonClassVer = returnTwoUsingAnonymousClass
println(anonClassVer.getDate)
println(anonClassVer.getStr)
```

Comment: Thanks.I didn't know about the anonymous class pattern. like you mentioned at first, it's hardly possible to say it has good readability though.
I end up choosing `Case Class`

Answer (score 1):

Sinse your logic with `Map[String,Any]` is more like *for each key I have one of ..* not *for each key I have both ...* more effective use in this case would be [`Either`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Either) or even more effectively - [scalaz.\/](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#package)

#### scalaz.\/

```
import scalaz._
import scalaz.syntax.either._

def getUserParam(userId: String): Map[String, String \/ Int \/ Boolean] = {
  //do something
  Map(
    "isExist" -> true.right,
    "userDataA" -> "String".left.left,
    "userDataB" -> 1.right.left
  )
}
```

`String \/ Int \/ Boolean` is left-associatited to `(String \/ Int) \/ Boolean`

now you have

```
def doSomething(foo: String){}
```

unluckily it's the most complex case, if for example you had

```
def doSomethingB(foo: Boolean){}
```

you could've just

```
foo("userDataA").foreach(doSomethingB)
```

since the ***right*** value considered as ***correct*** so for `String` which is  *left* to the *left* you could write

```
foo("userdata").swap.foreach(_.swap.foreach(doSomething))
```

#### Closed Family

Or you could craft you own simple type for large number of alternatives like

```
sealed trait Either3[+A, +B, +C] {
  def ifFirst[T](action: A => T): Option[T] = None
  def ifSecond[T](action: B => T): Option[T] = None
  def ifThird[T](action: C => T): Option[T] = None
}

case class First[A](x: A) extends Either3[A, Nothing, Nothing] {
  override def ifFirst[T](action: A => T): Option[T] = Some(action(x))
}

case class Second[A](x: A) extends Either3[Nothing, A, Nothing] {
  override def ifSecond[T](action: A => T): Option[T] = Some(action(x))
}

case class Third[A](x: A) extends Either3[Nothing, Nothing, A] {
  override def ifThird[T](action: A => T): Option[T] = Some(action(x))
}
```

now having

```
def getUserParam3(userId: String): Map[String, Either3[Boolean, String, Int]] = {
  //do something
  Map(
    "isExist" -> First(true),
    "userDataA" -> Second("String"),
    "userDataB" -> Third(1)
  )
}

val foo3 = getUserParam3("bar")
```

you can use your values as

```
foo3("userdata").ifSecond(doSomething)
```