# Better way to scan data using scala and spark

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark, side-effects

**Problem**

The input data has 2 types of records, lets call them `R` and `W`.

I need to traverse this data in Sequence from top to bottom in such a way that if the current record is of type `W`, it has to be merged with a map(lets call it `workMap`). If the key of that W-type record is already present in the map, the value of this record is added to it, otherwise a new entry is made into `workMap`.

If the current record is of type `R`, the `workMap` calculated until this record, is attached to the current record.

For example, if this is the order of records -

```
W1-   a -> 2
W2-   b -> 3
W3-   a -> 4
R1 
W4-   c -> 1
R2
W5-   c -> 4
```

Where W1, W2, W3, W4 and W5 are of type `W`; And R1 and R2 are of type `R`

At the end of this function, I should have the following -

```
R1 - { a -> 6, 
       b -> 3 } //merged(W1, W2, W3)
R2 - { a -> 6, 
       b -> 3,
       c -> 1 } //merged(W1, W2, W3, W4)
{ a -> 6, 
  b -> 3,
  c -> 5 } //merged(W1, W2, W3, W4, W5)
```

I want all the R-type records attached to the intermediate `workMap`s calculated until that point; And the final `workMap` after the last record is processed.

Here is the code that I have written -

```
def calcPerPartition(itr: Iterator[(InputKey, InputVal)]):
  Iterator[(ReportKey, ReportVal)] = {

    val workMap = mutable.HashMap.empty[WorkKey, WorkVal]
    val reportList = mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[(ReportKey, Reportval)]

    while (itr.hasNext) {
      val temp = itr.next()
      val (iKey, iVal) = (temp._1, temp._2)

      if (iKey.recordType == reportType) {
       //creates a new (ReportKey, Reportval)
        reportList += getNewReportRecord(workMap, iKey, iVal) 
      }
      else {
        //if iKey is already present, merge the values 
        //other wise adds a new entry
        updateWorkMap(workMap, iKey, iVal) 
      }
    }
    val workList: Seq[(ReportKey, ReportVal)] = workMap.toList.map(convertToReport)

    reportList.iterator ++ workList.iterator
  }
```

`ReportKey` class is like this -

```
case class ReportKey (
                        // the type of record - report or work 
                        rType: Int, 
                        date: String, 
                      .....
                       )
```

---

There are two problems with this approach that I am asking help for -

1. I have to keep track of a `reportList` - a list of `R` type records attached with intermediate `workMap`s. As the data grows, the `reportList` also grows and I am running into `OutOfMemoryException`s.
2. I have to combine `reportList` and `workMap` records in the same data structure and then return them. If there is any other elegant way, I would definitely consider changing this design.

For the sake of completeness - I am using spark. The function `calcPerPartition` is passed as argument for mapPartitions on an RDD. I need the `workMap`s from each partition to do some additional calculations later.

I know that if I don't have to return `workMap`s from each partition, the problem becomes much easier, like this -

```
...
val workMap = mutable.HashMap.empty[WorkKey, WorkVal]                     
itr.scanLeft[Option[(ReportKey, Reportval)]](
  None)((acc: Option[(ReportKey, Reportval)], 
  curr: (InputKey, InputVal)) => {

  if (curr._1.recordType == reportType) {
    val rec = getNewReportRecord(workMap, curr._1, curr._2)
    Some(rec)
  }
  else {
    updateWorkMap(workMap, curr._1, curr._2)
    None
  }
})

val reportList = scan.filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get)
//workMap is still empty after the scanLeft. 
...
```

Sure, I can do a `reduce` operation on the input data to derive the final `workMap` but I would need to look at the data twice. Considering that the input data set is huge, I want to avoid that too.

But unfortunately I need the `workMap`s at a latter step.

So, is there a better way to solve the above problem? If I can't solve problem 2 at all([according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907402/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-more-than-2-different-variable-type-values-in-sca)), is there any other way I can avoid storing `R` records(`reportList`) in a list or scan the data more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't yet have a better design for the second question - if you can avoid combining `reportList` and `workMap` into a single data structure but we can certainly avoid storing `R` type records in a list.

Here is how we can re-write the `calcPerPartition` from the above question -

```
def calcPerPartition(itr: Iterator[(InputKey, InputVal)]):
  Iterator[Option[(ReportKey, ReportVal)]] = {

    val workMap = mutable.HashMap.empty[WorkKey, WorkVal]
    var finalWorkMap = true

    new Iterator[Option[(ReportKey, ReportVal)]](){
        override def hasNext: Boolean = itr.hasNext

        override def next(): Option[(ReportKey, ReportVal)] = {
            val curr = itr.next()
            val iKey = curr._1
            val iVal = curr._2
            val eventKey = EventKey(openKey.date, openKey.symbol)

            if (iKey.recordType == reportType) {
              Some(getNewReportRecord(workMap, iKey, iVal))
            }
            else {
              //otherwise update the generic interest map but don't accumulate anything
              updateWorkMap(workMap, iKey, iVal)
              if (itr.hasNext) {
                next()
              }
              else {
                  if(finalWorkMap){
                    finalWorkMap = false //because we want a final only once
                    Some(workMap.map(convertToReport))
                  }
                  else {
                    None
                  }

              }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Instead of storing results in a list, we defined an iterator. That solved most of the memory issues we had around this issue.